# create similar different structures in C

Tags: c

I am quite new to C and I have a problem generating similar structures without repeating code. For example, I have the next linked list that is used in one function.

```
  typedef struct ll1{
    int oneArray[*m]; 
    struct ll2 *previous;
    double restOfValues[]; 
  }uniquePattern;
```

And of course, I have the related functions `free_ll1`,`addElement_ll1`, etc. The problem is that then I have another linked list such that

```
  typedef struct ll2{
    int oneArray[*n]; 
    struct ll2 *previous;
    double restOfValues[]; 
  }ll2;
```

Therefore I create the functions `free_ll2`, `addElement_ll2`, etc.

Would not be nice to have a function called `createllFunctions(int size,char *name)` that would create the actual structure and return an array of pointers to the functions that can free, add Element, and etc.

`size` would be the size of `oneArray` (`*n` and `*m` in this case) and `*name` would be the name of the structure inside `createllFunctions` which would be useful only inside the function itself.

The question is two sided. Is this a good idea or another pattern is use more commonly that I have overlooked? If is good, how would I implemented, particularly I do not know how to call `*name` to the structure itself.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need multiple types but only multiple objects of the same type:

```
typedef struct ll {
  int* oneArray;
  struct ll *previous;
} ll;
ll l1;
l1.previous = NULL;
l1.oneArray = malloc(number * sizeof(int));
ll l2;
l2.previous = &l1;
l2.oneArray = malloc(number2 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: sorry, I don't really get it, `oneArray` will still contain `*n` length array right?

Comment: there are two oneArray's: `l1.oneArray` and `l2.oneArray`

Comment: which they have the same length. I actually want two different objects, with different lengths in `oneArray`.

Comment: Actually using `*n` in the way you did cannot work even if `n` is constant. I made a version where each ll-link has a pointer to an array of different lengths.

Comment: I see, so can I have multiple elements inside a struct such that their size will get determined in runtime? that is a simple good solution.

Comment: this solution uses structs that have the same size, only the arrays they point to have different sizes.

Comment: meaning that I should `free` the array before freeing the structure. I see, I see... Did not think on that before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: correct. i forgot to mention that you have to `free` the arrays. sure!

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you want, but judging by your comments it might be something like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ll {
    struct ll *previous;
    /* double restOfValues[]; No idea what you want with this... */
    int oneArray[];
};
typedef struct ll ll;

ll *createllFunctions(int size)
{
    ll *node;

    node = malloc(sizeof(*node) + sizeof(int) * size);
    if (node)
        node->previous = NULL;

    return node;
}

/* Here follows an example. */

int main()
{
    ll *l1, *l2;
    int n1 = 64;
    int n2 = 57;

    l1 = createllFunctions(n1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        l1->oneArray[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        printf("%d, ", l1->oneArray[i]);

    puts("\n");

    l2 = createllFunctions(n2);
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        l2->oneArray[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        printf("%d, ", l2->oneArray[i]);

    puts("\n");
}
```

Comment: This code is interesting, but I think that my hole point of view in the question was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** to define nested functions in a function. Functions can only be called inside of another function. In C, functions are 'static objects' which are located explicitly in somewhere of the momory when the program are compiled, *pardon me for saying that informally*. So you can't "create" a function dynamically by calling this createllfunctions function.

An alternative for your case would be passing the array length as an argument of your functions instead of create a lot of functions.

```
typedef struct ll
{
    int* oneArray;  
    struct ll2 *previous;
    double restOfValues[]; 
}ll; 
void free_ll(int m);
void addElement_ll(int m);
```